# How to delete the bottom line of TextInput

Tags: react-native

I use the code for style:

```
const styles = {
    inputStyle: {
        color: '#000',
        paddingRight: 5,
        paddingLeft: 5,
        fontSize: 18,
        lineHeight: 23,
        flex: 2
    },
```

But it has a bottom line just like the right photo , how do i delete it that it show like the left photo ?
[image]

Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: set `<TextInput underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} />`

Comment: I forgot say that i compile on android device , thanks for your answer , it works !